# How can I create a link to download a static CSV file in www

Tags: r, shiny

I have a static CSV file called `sample.csv` inside `www/`. In my `ui.R` I tried doing

```
HTML("<a href='www/sample.csv' download>sample.csv</a>")
```

But when I attempt to download the file I get a "Failed - No file" error. Is there an easy way I can create a download link for static content like this or do I need to use the `downloadHandler()`?

Comment: ..we meet again. use download handler.or addResourcePath.  I'm guessing your server side isn't recognizing the action because it's just an a tag. if you look at actionLink you'll notice it's classed...which is how shiny knows to trigger an event bound in jquery. or.. maybe

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `actionLink`, but because the file is static and already in `www` maybe is easier only to use `tag$a`. You don't need to add the `www/` to the href, use something like:

```
tags$a(href = "sample.csv", target = "_blank", "sample.csv", title = "sample.csv")
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I found that it doesn't works on the embedded viewer of RStudio, you need to "show in a window" to use an external browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your actual URL, but what about this idea?

```
library(dplyr)
MyData2 <- read.csv(file="http://www.grex.org/~ev/breweries_geocode.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Or, this.

```
df <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", 
               header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)[1:6]
```